# Nested function variable scoping

Tags: python, scope, nested

## Failing Case

I ran across an `UnboundLocalError` exception that I could not understand.

I isolated the simplest chunk of the code:

```py
def wrapper_func():
   x = 0
   def test_unbound():
       x += 1
       return x
   return test_unbound()
```

Then if I call it:

```py
>>> wrapper_func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in wrapper_func
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in test_unbound
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

But as I understood it, `x` should be available to the inner function.

## Functioning Case

I tested it by doing something *almost* identical:

```py
def outer_func():
   x = 1
   def inner_func(val):
      print(val + x)
   inner_func(2)
```

If I test this out, no error:

```py
outer_func()
3
```

## What Am I Missing?

Can someone help me understand why the failing case fails and the successful case works?

Comment: Declare `nonlocal x` in the `inner()` function.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, @martineau, but can you explain why?

Comment: easy to fix. lemme answer

Comment: Because otherwise it will be considered a local variable. You can't use `global x` because `x` is not a global variable. As always,read the fine [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-nonlocal-stmt).